# Adding multiple account owners to a single Google Play developer account

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, google-play-services, google-developers-console

I have a Google Play developer account that I want to share with another user whom I want to add as an account owner so that we both have ownership over a certain app. However, despite giving him account permissions, the user is unable to access certain pages like the "Payment settings" page which is weird considering that I have given him all permissions for both app and account. I am kind of lost. Does that mean there can only be one account owner or is it that the other user also has to pay a $25 registration fee despite the fact that I have invited him? Or could it be a totally different reason?

Answer (score 1):

There can only be **one account owner**. You can have **multiple account admins**, but admins don't have [all the permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686) that the account owner has, like editing the payments settings for example.

Note that you cannot change the account owner, but you can [transfer the apps to another Play Store account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247).

Answer (score 0):

Try this page, it may help. They explain everything here.

[Dev account help users and permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686?hl=en)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I guess I was a bit confused as I thought an account admin was the same as the account owner but I guess it's not. So, from my understanding, it means that there can only be one account owner and only the account owner can have access to the payment settings right?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I also understood that only the owner has access to the payment stuff and other roles have some other pre-defined access.